# Subplot for Seaborn lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to create a 1X2 plot, I try subplot but lmplot don't have parameter 'ax',
Not work

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
sns.lmplot(data = table2, x='hour_6_10', y = 'all_day', ax = axes[0])
```

I want to use these line for subplot:

```
sns.lmplot(data = table2, x='hour_6_10', y = 'all_day')
sns.lmplot(data = table2, x='hour_0_10', y = 'all_day')
```

My data has 3 columns like this, so I don't use parameter 'hue' for Facetgrid [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFuJg.png)

Please give solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`regplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot) instead of `lmplot()`.

From the documentation for lmplot:

> Notes
>
> The regplot() and lmplot() functions are closely related, but the
> former is an axes-level function while the latter is a figure-level
> function that combines regplot() and FacetGrid.

**ALTERNATIVELY**
You could ["melt"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt) your dataframe and use `lmpolot()` to generate a FacetGrid with your three data columns. But you haven't provided a copiable code for your dataframe, so I cannot tell you the exact syntax you would need.

Comment: hi, I have a picture of my dataframe which you could base on @Diziet Asahi